# Methods for Checking Business Rules

Tags: .net, vb.net, theory

I hope this is in the right place. I was having a discussion with a colleague about a method used to check business rules.  In general there are two conditions:

1. "If one fails the whole thing fails"

Example 1: "If one fails the whole thing fails"

I have used the following technique for condition 1 in several cases.  Essentially if one of those conditions is false then the whole thing fails

```
Dim blnTemp As Boolean = True

If Fail=False Then blnTemp = blnTemp AndAlso False

    {code code code}

If Fail=True Then blnTemp = blnTemp AndAlso False

    {code code code}

If Fail=False Then blnTemp = blnTemp AndAlso False

    {code code code}

If Fail=False Then blnTemp = blnTemp AndAlso False

    {yup, code code code}

If True Then
    Execute("Execute Global Thermal Nuclear War")
End If
```

**So I am wondering if anyone has any other techniques that they have used for rule checks?**

Comment: It all depends on what your business rules are.  If a condition fails and you need to reprocesses or warn your user the ifs are fine (apart from them all evaluating as false currently).  If your code should stop then throw a new exception explaining the problem.

Comment: @Rene147.  Agreed.  So how do you collect the information?  What style do you use.  So far I have learned of the "Specification Patter" which I am investigating.

Answer (score 3):

I usually try to go with the "Fail fast, fail hard" idea. Basically leaving the method as soon as the first required condition is not met.

```
Public Function NuclearWar() as Boolean
   If not is Foo() then return False
   If (FooList is Nothing AndAlso FooList.Count = 0) then return False
   (...) etc.

   return True
End Function
```

For me, its clearer to read instead of going down each check and return the result at the end. If the "whole thing" fails if one of the conditions is false, that early jump off comes in quite handy - as long as you don't need to examine the result of the other checks which are left out because of the return.

@Comment

> but if your conditions are separated by other work that needs to be
>   done then one function call would not be sufficient. Or would it? What
>   would you do

Well, readability and clean code (Which includes easy following of the control flow) is one of the things I care about. So I'd most likely group conditions which are related together. If the conditions are separated by other work, I'd abstract the conditions in a class, say `LaunchConditions`.

```
Public Class LaunchCondition
    Public Property IsLaunch As Boolean
    ' Add other properties you'd like to check
End Class
Public Class LaunchConditions
    Private _launchConditions = New List(Of LaunchCondition)
    Public ReadOnly Property CanLaunch As Boolean
        Get
            Return CheckConditions()
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub AddCondition(ByVal condition As LaunchCondition)
        ' Add condition
    End Sub
    Public Sub RemoveCondition(ByVal condition As LaunchCondition)
        ' Add condition
    End Sub
    Private Function CheckConditions() As Boolean
        ' Your check logic
        Return _launchConditions.Any(Function(x As LaunchCondition) Not x.IsLaunch)
    End Function
End Class
```

Hope this gives you some ideas :)

Comment: I understand, but in the example there is no return.  Were not in a function, we are deciding whether not not to execute section of code.  I could wrap the code within a function and then it would work, but the assumption is you can not do that.

Comment: I suppose your style would suggest wrapping it in a function which I think is an awesome answer and most likely a better practice, but if your conditions are separated by other work that needs to be done then one function call would not be sufficient.  Or would it?  What would you do.

Comment: FYI, I edited example 1 to illustrate what I am talking about.

Comment: This and the Specification Approach are exactly what I was looking for.  For complex high processing business logic I think it provides a more flexible way to handle conditions rather than using conditionals and branching.  I am guessing there are also benefits when it comes times to test.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

For me, Linq does the job concisely and easily readable.

```
Dim nuclearWarConditions As IEnumerable(Of Boolean) = New Boolean() { _
    True, _
    True, _
    True, _
    False, _
    True
}

If nuclearWarConditions.All(Function(condition) condition = True) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Execute Global Thermal Nuclear War")
End If
```

Analogically, you may use

```
If nuclearWarConditions.Any(Function(condition) condition = False) Then
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Cancelled Global Thermal Nuclear War")
End If
```

to reduce nesting.

*Edit: Sorry in case i messed up the VB syntax. I'm not a native speaker :)*

Comment: Interesting approach.  Here is my one comment, if the rules fail at condition 4 and condition 5 is heavy processing then I don't want to bother executing it for performance reasons.

Comment: In fact, `IEnumerable.All` and `IEnumerable.Any` practice premature evaluation. So yes, sorting your list of conditions by processing time is advised!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the difference is between your two scenarios - isn't "all must be true" the same as "if one fails the whole thing fails"?

In any case, assuming your processing is already done, I wouldn't mess with all the If/Then statements, but go with something cleaner:

```
if (conditional1 && conditional2 && conditional3...)
    {return true}
else
    {return false}
```

Comment: There is no difference except for clarity.  Sometimes the business rule states one or the other and it makes sense to code it that way so it's easier to follow for the next guy.

Comment: @wavedrop: code readability make a huge difference. Also, have look at the specification patter , it allow a to implement a clean validation. Some links here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern .  Here an example : http://devlicio.us/blogs/jeff_perrin/archive/2006/12/13/the-specification-pattern.aspx

Comment: Guy - I simplified the code because I thought it was confusing.  Only 1 example now and if you needed you just flip the conditions.

Comment: I stated this in a comment above "but if your conditions are separated by other work that needs to be done then one function {condition statement} would not be sufficient"

Comment: @GiorgioMinardi Thank you.  This is inline with what I was searching for but did not now existed.  Looks like it applies nicely to complicated business logic.